# How to include dummy variables in ivreg model?

Tags: stata

I have the following model:

```
ivreg ldemand social_housing transport year (lprice = utilities)
```

However, I want to make `year` as a dummy variable.

How can I do it in Stata?

Using `i.year` doesn't work for the `ivreg` command.

Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1451808-how-to-include-dummy-variables-in-ivreg-model-in-stata).

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please also consider up-voting it using the upper arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `ivreg` does not allow factor variables:

```
. webuse hsng2, clear

. ivreg rent pcturban i.region (hsngval = faminc)
factor variables not allowed
r(101);
```

However, you can still use the `xi` prefix to create dummies on the fly:

```
.  xi: ivreg rent pcturban  i.region (hsngval = faminc)
i.region          _Iregion_1-4        (naturally coded; _Iregion_1 omitted)

Instrumental variables (2SLS) regression

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        50
-------------+----------------------------------   F(5, 44)        =      9.10
       Model |  12735.4667         5  2547.09334   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  48507.6533        44  1102.44667   R-squared       =    0.2079
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1179
       Total |    61243.12        49  1249.85959   Root MSE        =    33.203

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        rent |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     hsngval |   .0038683   .0008958     4.32   0.000     .0020629    .0056737
    pcturban |  -.4980121   .5179779    -0.96   0.342    -1.541928    .5459039
  _Iregion_2 |   1.528672   15.14086     0.10   0.920    -28.98572    32.04306
  _Iregion_3 |    7.74279   15.10906     0.51   0.611    -22.70752     38.1931
  _Iregion_4 |  -40.61235   19.60999    -2.07   0.044    -80.13369   -1.091002
       _cons |   88.26681   31.69154     2.79   0.008     24.39671    152.1369
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  hsngval
Instruments:   pcturban _Iregion_2 _Iregion_3 _Iregion_4 faminc
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is important to note that according to the command's help file:

> **Out-of-date command**
>
> **ivreg** is an out-of-date command as of Stata 10. **ivreg** has been replaced with the **ivregress** command.

Thus, it is best to switch to `ivregress` instead:

```
. ivregress 2sls rent pcturban i.region (hsngval = faminc), small
  
Instrumental variables (2SLS) regression

      Source |       SS       df       MS         Number of obs   =         50
-------------+------------------------------      F(  5,    44)   =       9.10
       Model |  12735.4667     5  2547.09334      Prob > F        =     0.0000
    Residual |  48507.6533    44  1102.44667      R-squared       =     0.2079
-------------+------------------------------      Adj R-squared   =     0.1179
       Total |    61243.12    49  1249.85959      Root MSE        =     33.203

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        rent |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     hsngval |   .0038683   .0008958     4.32   0.000     .0020629    .0056737
    pcturban |  -.4980121   .5179779    -0.96   0.342    -1.541928    .5459039
             |
      region |
    N Cntrl  |   1.528672   15.14086     0.10   0.920    -28.98572    32.04306
      South  |    7.74279   15.10906     0.51   0.611    -22.70752     38.1931
       West  |  -40.61235   19.60999    -2.07   0.044    -80.13369   -1.091002
             |
       _cons |   88.26681   31.69154     2.79   0.008     24.39671    152.1369
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  hsngval
Instruments:   pcturban 2.region 3.region 4.region faminc
```

Type `help ivregress` from Stata's command prompt for more details.